# Not able to convert images to Webp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webp

I'm trying to convert png to webp using npm i webp-converter

Followinwg is the code

```
const imagemin = require("imagemin");
const webp = require("imagemin-webp");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const fileTypes = [".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg"];
const basePath = `${process.cwd()}/images`;

const convertImages = async (file) => {
    if (!fileTypes.includes(path.extname(file))) {
        return;
    }
    let dest = path.join(__dirname, "../convertOutput")
    if (!fs.existsSync(dest)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dest);
    }
    const config = {
        destination:"./convertOutput",
        plugins: [webp({ quality: 75 })],
    };
    await console.log(`[${file}] Start to convert⋯⋯`);
    await imagemin([file], config);
    await console.log(`Convert [${file}] to WebP already！`);
};

const exploreDirectory = (dirPath) => {
    fs.readdirSync(dirPath).forEach(async (item) => {
        const itemPath = path.join(dirPath, item);
        const stats = fs.statSync(itemPath);

        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            exploreDirectory(itemPath);
        } else if (stats.isFile()) {
            await convertImages(itemPath);
        }
    });
}

exploreDirectory(basePath);
```

When I run that code, I get the message

```
[C:\net\source\source\images\fubangyilyu2.png] Start to convert⋯⋯
Convert [C:\net\source\source\images\fubangyilyu2.png] to WebP already！
```

and I can see any webp in the floder named convertOutput